# How do I stop palm trees from sprouting from the side?

Tags: tree-care, palm

My 6-7 year-old outdoor date palm trees are growing side-sprouts, resulting in multiple trunks. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Many trees do this.  This may be their natural habit.  If you'd prefer a single trunk the thing to do is prune the shoots as soon as you're aware of them so that the roots aren't wasting too much energy on them instead of your main trunk.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a clumping Senegal date palm, Pheonix reclinata, or hybrid variety. Which will always have bottom growth. If that is the case, trimming as previously answered is your best bet.